# How to remove Windows and keep ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, windows-10, grub-efi

[image]I have 2 Operating systems, Windows 10 and Ubuntu. Both installed on different drives. I wish to completely remove Windows 10 and the space occupied by Windows 10 to be added to Ubuntu. How do I do that? (I don't know if this is important or not, my laptop supports UEFI boot)

Comment: Boot your Ubuntu partition and open `Gparted`, [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/860893/edit) with a screenshot of how your partitions look.

Comment: you can format the windows partition. You have to watch out though that your bootloader is not on that partition. And you should update it afterwards.

Comment: Also note that there is inherent danger in resizing and reformatting partitions, so please ***keep backups***.

Comment: See [How to Resize Partitions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) and [How do I add this extra partition to my installed Ubuntu system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/565106/how-do-i-add-this-extra-partition-to-my-installed-ubuntu-system). Each approach (resizing partitions or re-purposing the existing Windows partitions) has merit.

Comment: I only see one drive in your gparted screen shot (that's normal). I would prefer if you could [edit] and include the output of `sudo parted -l` since you mention 2 drives I think it's best we see both before jumping to a conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu installer easily lets you erase Windows and replace it with Ubuntu.

Here is what you have to do :

1. Backup your data !
   All of your data will be wiped with your Windows installation so do not miss this step.
2. Create a bootable USB Ubuntu installation.
3. Boot the Ubuntu installation USB drive and choose **erase everything** and *install* Ubuntu.
4. Follow the installation process ...
   and at the step Installation Type select Replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Does this work even if ubuntu is already installed?

Comment: No, this is for if only Windows is installed.